# Setting Outlook appointment data through a userform

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to set Outlook appointments from a `userform` in `Excel`. The code works if I am referencing cells. How do I reference boxes in a `userform`? I also need to add to the code recipients for the meeting which I would reference from a different list worksheet.

Here is the code that references the cells in Excel which works by clicking a button in the worksheet:

```
Sub AddAppointments()
    ' Create the Outlook session
    Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Start at row 2
r = 2

Do Until Trim(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
    ' Create the AppointmentItem
    Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)
    ' Set the appointment properties
    myApt.Subject = Cells(r, 1).Value
    myApt.Location = Cells(r, 2).Value
    myApt.Start = Cells(r, 3).Value
    myApt.Duration = Cells(r, 4).Value
    ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
    If Trim(Cells(r, 5).Value) = "" Then
        myApt.BusyStatus = 2
    Else
        myApt.BusyStatus = Cells(r, 5).Value
    End If
    If Cells(r, 6).Value > 0 Then
        myApt.ReminderSet = True
        myApt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(r, 6).Value
    Else
        myApt.ReminderSet = False
    End If
    myApt.Body = Cells(r, 7).Value
    myApt.Display
    r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

This is my attempt at changing the code to reference boxes in a userform:

```
Private Sub Cmdappointment_Click()

Dim outlookapp As Object
'the mail item is the contents inside a mail
Dim mitem As AppointmentItem
'created outlook app
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
'it will open a new application
Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
'Set mail item
Set mitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Do Until userform2.TextBox4.Value = ""

    ' Create the AppointmentItem
    Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)

    ' Set the appointment properties
    On Error Resume Next

    mitem

        myApt.Subject = Me.texbox4.Value
        myApt.Location = Me.texbox3.Value
        myApt.Start = Me.ComboBox1.Value
        myApt.Duration = Me.ComboBox2.Value
        ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
        If Me.ComboBox3.Value = "" Then
            myApt.BusyStatus = 2
        Else
            myApt.BusyStatus = Me.ComboBox3.Value
        End If
        If Me.TextBox1.Value > 0 Then
            myApt.ReminderSet = True
            myApt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Me.TextBox1.Value
        Else
            myApt.ReminderSet = False
        End If
        myApt.Body = Me.TextBox2.Value
        myApt.Display

    End With
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I would suggest commenting the line `On Error Resume Next` to know what error is being thrown, then you would be able to proceed further easily.

Comment: If i comment on error resume next, the error message i get is: invalid use of me keyword. under my appointment.subject

Comment: There you go, replace all `me` with explicit reference to `UserForm`.

Comment: i dont get any error messages but when i press the cmdappointment button in the userform nothing happens, here is the new code:

Comment: I hope you did not replace `Me.texbox4.Value` with `Userform.texbox4.Value`. You should do `userform2.texbox4.Value`. As that is the actual userform object.

Comment: Private Sub cmdappointment()

Dim outlookapp As Object
'the mail item is the contents inside a mail
Dim mitem As AppointmentItem
'created outlook app
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
'it will open a new application
Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
'Set mail item
Set mitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Comment: Also keep in mind and keep `On Error Resume Next` commented till you resolve all the problems.

Comment: You can post the code as an answer if you like.

Comment: no i used userform2.textbox4.value

Comment: i posted the new code but still no luck, sorry for being a headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub cmdappointment_Click()
    ' Create the Outlook session
    Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    Do Until userform2.TextBox4.Value = ""
        ' Create the AppointmentItem
        Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)
        ' Set the appointment properties
        myApt.Subject = userform2.TextBox4.Value
        myApt.Location = userform2.TextBox3.Value
        myApt.Start = userform2.ComboBox1.Value
        myApt.Duration = userform2.ComboBox2.Value
        ' If Busy Status is not specified, default to 2 (Busy)
        If userform2.ComboBox3.Value = "" Then
            myApt.BusyStatus = 2
        Else
            myApt.BusyStatus = userform2.ComboBox3.Value
        End If
        If userform2.TextBox1.Value > 0 Then
            myApt.ReminderSet = True
            myApt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = userform2.TextBox1.Value
        Else
            myApt.ReminderSet = False
        End If
        myApt.Body = userform2.TextBox2.Value
        myApt.Display
    Exit Do
    Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)` with `Set myApt = outlookapp.CreateItem(1)`. Mind you even if this works the code is not right yet.

Comment: the new code works for me only if all the boxes are filled except busy status. i would have to add a message box for that which is easy. I am having issues adding recipients to the code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry couldn't fit the code in the comments so here are a couple of issues...

You are creating `outlookapp` and using `myOutlook` Object.
And also you are creating two mail items `mitem` and `myApt` each respectively from `outlookapp` and `myOutlook`. Eventually using only `myApt`. I do not know the origins of `myOutlook`. But I would rewrite the code to use just one set. **One set of OutLook and MailItem objects just like in your worksheet application**

```
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
'it will open a new application
Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
'Set mail item
Set mitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Do Until userform2.TextBox4.Value = ""

    ' Create the AppointmentItem
    Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)
```

---

To add recipients do the below

```
myApt.Recipients.Add('j doe')
```

---

To make it a bit more safe I would add the below line as well

```
Dim myApt As AppointmentItem
```

Comment: @jdoee did that help? I can correct the code if you like? But it is literally what is there in your ss code, for the block I pasted.